# How can I make the row of a listView slide in a fragment?

Tags: android, mobile, android-listview, slide

[image: Hi there. How can I implement "slide to delete" row in a fragment.]

Is it possible withoust using any special libraries? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you mean slide as in slide out, a quick fix is to use a `ViewPager`.  This is available in the support library. Simply extend `ViewPagerAdapter` and add the functionality you want. (aka. remove the item from the list, mark it as done, etc.)

Assuming you mean slide as in scroll, a `HorizontalScrollView` should suffice.

Comment: Another library that you may be interested is Gabriele Mariotti's [cardslib](https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib).  It has a `CardWithList` class with built in swipable functionality. See a tutorial [here](https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib/blob/master/doc/CARDWITHLIST.md#how-to-build-a-card-with-a-linearlist).